# Refactoring the given for-in loop with a higher order function

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming, photosframework

Given the following code:

```
let assetsFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: panoramasCollection, options: fetchOptions)
private var pAssets = [PHAsset]()
for i in 0..<assetsFetchResult.count {
    let asset = assetsFetchResult.object(at: i)
    pAssets.append(asset)
}
```

How can refactor the for-in loop using a higher order function such as `map`, `filter`, or `reduce`? As you can see I am dependent on the index variable and the various higher order functions don't seem to give me the index in their respective closures.

Comment: The higher order functions in swift :- map, filter, reduce, etc... There seems to know function like "iterate" which would give me the index and the value in the closure. Would I have to create my own?

Comment: Are you asking how to populate the `pAssets` array without using the `for i in` loop?

Comment: @rmaddy yesss!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "higher order functions" such as `map`, `filter`, etc. do not apply to `PHFetchResult` which is what `assetsFetchResult` is.

You can do:

```
private var pAssets = [PHAsset]()
assetsFetchResult.enumerateObjects { (asset, index, stop) in
    pAssets.append(asset)
}
```

Comment: No. You cannot say `for asset in assetsFetchResult`. That's the problem.

Comment: @matt Oops. I got thrown off by the fact that the documentation states that `PHFetchResult` conforms to `NSFastEnumeration`. I removed that part of the answer.

Comment: Yes, it used to be possible to make PHFetchResult conform to Sequence by taking advantage of its NSFastEnumeration conformance. But that is no longer possible. As I've said, I regard that as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately PHFetchResult cannot be enumerated as if were a Swift Sequence (i.e. with `for...in`). It used to be possible to do that by a clever sleight-of-hand, but then they turned PHFetchResult into a generic and ruined it.

This is even more frustrating because in Objective-C you *can* enumerate it with `for...in`.

In Swift, you simply have to use the Cocoa method provided for this purpose (or use indexes).

Comment: If it's any comfort, I have a bug filed on this issue: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1576

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it! But you need range because `PHFetchResult` isn't collection.

```
let assetsFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: panoramasCollection, options: fetchOptions)
private var pAssets = (0..<assetsFetchResult.count).map(assetsFetchResult.object(at:))
```